# How to generate sorted scripts in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016, ssms-2016

I'm looking for a way to generate sorted DDL scripts with `SQL Server Management Studio` with "Tasks" -> "Generate Scripts..."

I don't see any option about sorting in "`Advanced`" tab, and after the export I have views, functions, tables, etc... in random order.

I want a sorted export, alphabetical (A-Z), of all objects in the Database.

Comment: I think the script is generated in dependency order rather than random. Otherwise, creation of views would fail would fail if the referenced table, view, or function hasn't yet been created.

Comment: @MitchWheat Because I have to do a compare with the DDL of another database, which are sorted alphabetically

Comment: or you could create a VS database project and compare schema that way. more reliable than comparing text files

Comment: @MitchWheat It would be great, but I can't: I don't have VS installed in the RDP host that the third party supplier has given to us.

Comment: @DanGuzman I think you're right, but there's no chance to do an export with alphabetical order?

Comment: If you want to compare schema without SSDT, generate one script per object and compare folders with a text compare utility.

Comment: @DanGuzman one script per object for 1300 objects? :D No way isn't acceptable...

Comment: Then use SSDT for schema compare. It's a tool designed for the job. Alternatively, script yourself using [SMO Scripter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter) (e.g. from PowerShell) so you have full control over the scripting order and options.